# pos for .net - slow startup with espon printer

Tags: epson, pos-for-.net

I am developing a software in c# (VS2010, .net 4, pos for .net), i found out that when i open and claim the printer before printing, it's super slow, it takes couple seconds, same with the cash drawer. Why is it so and how could I make it faster?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this behaviour on networked devices (network receipt printer instead of USB) - is this the case for you as well?

I ended up reverting to USB instead of Network because of this.